# MYSQL count only users who have answered the most questions in the last 30 days

Tags: mysql

**Currently I have:**

```
SELECT user.userid, Username, count(answerid) as Answers 
FROM user left outer join answer on user.userid=answer.userid
group by user.userid
order by Answers desc
limit 0,5
```

This counts the users that have answered the most questions. However I would like to change this to count only the top 5 users who have answered the most **questions IN the last 30 days**.

The answer table has a field called date1 which contains the date when the answers was posted. Any ideas please? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a where clause:

```
SELECT user.userid, Username, count(answerid) as Answers 
FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN answer ON user.userid=answer.userid
WHERE answer.date1 >= date_sub(curdate(),interval 30 day)
GROUP BY user.userid
ORDER BY Answers desc
LIMIT 0,5
```

But as others suggested it would be better to query without the outer join - something like this should work:

```
SELECT user.userid, Username, answer_count.Answers
FROM user,
    (SELECT userid, count(answerid) as Answers FROM answer
     WHERE date1 >= date_sub(curdate(),interval 30 day
     GROUP BY userid) answer_count
WHERE user.userid = answer_count.userid
ORDER BY answer_count.Answers desc
LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: This query said "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

Comment: It works inversely but not like this. However I am sure that there are profiles who posted answers in the last 30 days. Still the query returns no results.

Comment: you might `select distinct date1 from answer order by date1 desc` and check the most recent values

Comment: Using the outer join means that the query is far from ideal for the purpose stated ("This counts the users that have answered the most questions") let alone for the purpose the OP is asking about. And it's even more absurd for the last 30 day constraint.

Comment: @pacey: I presume you mean your query will very if there are posts in the alst 30 days to report on - not a solution to the question originall asked?

Comment: @symcbean yes, it was to verify the values not to solve the question.

Comment: Indeed, the outer join is crazy. I was just answering the question about how to do the date limit; I've added an alternative query now